# my data is not going to realtime database

Tags: flutter

DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child( 'users');

```
                  String uid = credential.user!.uid;
                  int dt = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

                  await userRef.child(uid).set({
                    "fullName": fullName,
                    'email': email,
                    'uid': uid,
                    'dt': dt,
                    'profileImage': ''

                  });
```

Comment: Hello Faizy, can you add some details to your questions please? do you have any errors in the console? do you have any value in your firebase console? which platform you are working on? look also at this link to improve how you can ask your question on Stackoverflow! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more information about your issue?

However, according to my understanding, you can use `push()` to generate a new child location before overwriting it using `set()`

```dart
userRef.child(uid).push().set({
      "fullName": fullName,
      'email': email,
      'uid': uid,
      'dt': dt,
      'profileImage': ''

    });
```